# How to Create Flavour with different applicationId Android?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I need to create 4 apps. All 4 apps will differ only by UI and package name(application Id). To approval from the client, I have created 1 full working app.

Now I need to create other 3 apps which all have their own applicationId and theme.
The code will remain the same for all 4 apps.

To achieve that I have created flavors as below. But all the time I am getting "generated com.xxx.R class cannot be found".

Only the 1 app which I have created first only it works. Its applicationId is "com.bbb.app". All java files are under this package.

```
flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
    b{
        applicationId "com.bbb.app"
        dimension "default"
    }
    a{
        applicationId "com.aaa.app"
        dimension "default"
    }

    x {
        applicationId "com.xxx.app"
        dimension "default"
    }

}
```

When I choose any applicationId except default one, annotation files also not resolved. Like cannot find symbol class HomeFragment_.

Please suggest If I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: have you clean or rebuild the project and try to run ?

Comment: @SandeepMalik I only post a question on SO when nothing is worked. Done lot many times.